# Auto-syncing code repositories country wise

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

So our development team is spread across multiple countries and code repository is hosted in United states.
Now Problem is except U.S, commits & pull from other countries take too much time. 
Is there any way we can host code repository country wise and it ll auto-sync to seem like one(having commits and changes from all countries)?

Comment: Do you use git or mercurial? And for git, there is no such setting, but you can use your own script and execute it in schedule.

Comment: No matter what version control software you use, there will still need to be human involvement with attempting to merge conflicts between the supposed 'masters'.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT We use mercurial. could you point me out to what kind of script we are looking at here? any resources ?

Comment: @Phylogenesis That is what i thought. is there any alternative?

Comment: Check [this email](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2015-May/048340.html) and thread which it started.

Comment: as linked in the e-mail thread: use incoming changeset hooks to sync the repositories. However merging work will likely need human supervision - at least on an occasional basis when conflicts occur. You might want to review merges manually even when no conflict occurs, though